# Angular: display json array as a dynamic matrix

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to display the score of each user by date in a matrix. Each user can only have one score per date.
 I want the matrix to have the following look:

```
Date         User1   User2   User3
2020-01-05   40      20      20
2020-01-03   40      30      -
2019-12-02    -      23      -
```

I get the data from an API and get an json-arry with objects that has the date, user and score. Is there any way to display the data from the json-response as the matrix above? 
I tried playing around with *ngFor with different nesting but did not manage to retrive the desired result.
Do I need to rearrange the data in another structure before trying to display it?

Example of the json:

```
{ 
   "results":[ 
      { 
         "date":"2020-01-05",
         "user":"user1",
         "score":40
      },
      { 
         "date":"2020-01-05",
         "user":"user2",
         "score":20
      },
      { 
         "date":"2020-01-05",
         "user":"user3",
         "score":20
      },
      { 
         "date":"2020-01-03",
         "user":"user1",
         "score":40
      },
      { 
         "date":"2020-01-03",
         "user":"user2",
         "score":30
      },
      { 
         "date":"2019-12-02",
         "user":"user2",
         "score":23
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code builds matrix which you want to get:

```js
const data = {
    "results": [
        {
            "date": "2020-01-05",
            "user": "user1",
            "score": 40
        }
        ...
    ]
};

const users = Array.from(new Set(data.results.map(i => i.user)));
const dates = Array.from(new Set(data.results.map(i => i.date)));

const result = [
    ['Date', ...users],    // first row (header)
    ...dates.map(date => { // other rows
        return [
            date,          // first column (date)
            ...users.map(user => { // value columns
                const currentDateUser = data.results.find(i => i.user === user && i.date === date);
                return currentDateUser ? currentDateUser.score : '-';
            })
        ];
    })
];
```